# What is the meaning of the command `sudo nmap -sP -n 192.168.0.0-255`?

Tags: linux, command-line, nmap

What is the meaning of the following command and why its not given at help menu of `nmap`?

Sample command: `sudo nmap -sP -n 192.168.0.0-255`

Sample output:

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-14 16:09 +06
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.1
Host is up (0.0035s latency).
MAC Address: 20:L6:A7:55:3D:44 (D-link Technologies)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.104
Host is up (0.20s latency).
MAC Address: 18:97:F8:15:26:D9 (Zen Mobile Communication Technology)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.118
Host is up.
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 6.31 seconds
```

What does `-sP` mean and why is it used?

This command works properly, but it is not listed to man and help menu.

Please elaborate the circumstances.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Why is this tagged question-answering?

Comment: sorry in this case, I am a newbie and never used this side...I tagged question-answering thinking this section is used to getting answers

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> In previous releases of Nmap, **-sn** was known as **-sP**..